# How to import subpackage when it has the same name as a package in Python?

Tags: python, pypi, python-packaging

Let's say I'm writing a package called "some_package". Its file structure is as follows:

```
some_package
│   .gitignore
│   NEWS.md
│   README.md
│   requirements.txt
│   setup.py
│
├───tests
│       test_some_package.py
│       __init__.py
│
└───some_package
        some_package.py
        __init__.py
```

As you can see, "some_package" only has a single subpackage with the same name, which in turn has only one module, also with the same name.

Inside my unit tests (under `./tests/test_some_package.py`) I am able to import all functions from the `./some_package/some_package.py` module by using:

```
from some_package import some_package
```

However, if I just use:

```
import some_package
```

Then, for whatever function inside it, I get an attribute error telling me that the module "some_package" has no attribute called <whatever_function>.

What am I doing wrong? Is this bad practice? What should I use instead?

**EDIT**: I want to be able to just write `import some_package` and have access to every function inside `./some_package/some_package.py`.

Comment: Doesn't your question already contain the answer? If you want to use the functions inside `some_package.py`, just use `from some_package import some_package`.

Comment: sure, but that seems bad from a user perspective. I want anyone who installs my package to be able to just `import some_package`  and that's it. ESPECIALLY considering the module has the same name.

Comment: I misread.  I agree with @Stephen, I don't see a problem

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: You should be able to put `from some_package.some_package import *` in the `__init__.py` of `some_package` to achieve what you want, but generally you would just move the functionality to that file instead, otherwise you run into the problem you can see above with odd relative imports and ambiguity.

Comment: @Stephen, thanks that does work. Would you mind writing a proper answer and also explaining why does that work? Would appreciate it very much!